# Object Required error on Report Load Ms Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, report

I have a pretty simple if statement for a control source of an unbound field.  I'm getting an Object Required error, and can't quite figure it out.  Basically, if the LastName field is not empty, then the first control source applies, else, the second one applies.  (Basically dropping the word "and" in the string)

---

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
    If LastName2.Value Is NotNull Then
        Text29.ControlSource = [=[FirstName1] & " " & [LastName1] & " AND " & [FirstName2] & " " & [LastName2]]
    Else
        Text29.ControlSource = [=[FirstName1] & " " & [LastName1] & "  " & [FirstName2] & " " & [LastName2]]
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ControlSource` property expects as string. So place the expression used as control source in a string:

```
If Not IsNull(LastName2.Value) Then
'Or  Nz(LastName2) <> ""
    Text29.ControlSource = "=FirstName1 & ' ' & LastName1 & ' AND ' & FirstName2 & ' ' & LastName2"
Else
    Text29.ControlSource = "=FirstName1 & ' ' & LastName1 & '  ' & FirstName2 & ' ' & LastName2"
End If
```

Note that in the expression within the string, you can use single quotes as string delimiters. Also, since the column names are not reserved keywords, you don't need to embed them in to brackets  [ ... ].

Use `Not IsNull(xy)` instead of `xy Is NotNull`.

Comment: Same error.  MS Access is highlighting this portion of the function;   

If LastName2.Value Is NotNull Then

Comment: Interesting... if I move the expression to On_Open then the error is "You have entered and expression that has no value."   the field LastName2 is on the report, but with a "not displayed" variable.

Comment: OK, so after changing the Not IsNull section to your suggestion, the error is gone, but it only executes the first portion of the "if" regardless of value or not in the LastName2 field.

Comment: If `LastName2` is a textbox it will never be null, but have an empty string instead (`LastName2 = ""`). If it is a database column it might be null or be an empty string. You can safely test for both conditions with `Nz(LastName2) <> ""`. It could contain whitespaces as well. Then test with: `Trim$(Nz(LastName2)) <> ""`